# Do not expand string inside variable

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
a="$(date)"
echo $a
```

I want the result of that echo be `$(date)`, not the actual date.
How to achive that?

Comment: Dare I ask why you would want to store a shell command substitution, unexpanded, in a variable?  Storing code in variables is sometimes, but very seldom, the right thing to do.

Comment: The real case was with the $PS1 variable.
The thing is i wanted to know where was defined, so i needed the code to do a grep in files, but when i did echo "$PS1" it was interpreted.
Anyway, i could find the location without doing this, but the question remained, if it was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with double quotes, as the assignment had taken place in the first line. Unless you escape the dollar sign:

```
$ a="\$(date)"
$ echo "$a"
$(date)
$ eval echo "$a"
Fri 5 Oct 18:53:45 CEST 2018
```

And with single quotes, you might do these:

```
$ a='$(date)'
$ echo "$a"
$(date)
$ eval echo "$a"
Fri 5 Oct 16:45:45 CEST 2018
```

Comment: of course you can, you just have to escape the `$`

Comment: Hmm, so there is no way to tell a="$(date)" to print just the value, without beign interpreted? The question came because i'm echoing a variable and i'm getting the result, but i would like to know the code behind.

Comment: @Nestoter See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `''` insted of `""`

```
a='$(date)'
```